# Copy documents from one document library to another in different farms in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a document library with few columns/properties. I am writing a scheduled job to copy the documents based on the flag.

Could you someone tell me, how can I copy the selected documents to destination farm which is having same schema?

Comment: Yes I could but that would include using a plugin to be able to synchronize the libraries. Still interested?

Answer (score 0):

I myself have not encountered this specific scenario having only worked with one farm but this might help:

[Content Deployment](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261732%28office.12%29.aspx)

[Visual Guide](http://blog.beckybertram.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=83)

Comment: I would like to do the same for List items also. Is it possible to connect one farm from another farm?